# Local font not loading in NextJs

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, fonts, local

I am trying to load the local font 'Stigfier' through my 'styles/styles.css' global css and it is not loading. My google fonts loaded in the '_document.jsx' work fine.

```
  @font-face {
    font-family: Stigfier;
    src:
         url('/../public/fonts/stigfier/Stigfier.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/../public/fonts/stigfier/Stigfier.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('/../public/fonts/stigfier/Stigfier.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/../public/fonts/stigfier/Stigfier.otf') format('opentype');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}

body {
    font-family: Stigfier;
}
```

But it is not loading, same with the [recommended way in the Nextjs website docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/font-optimization):

```
import localFont from '@next/font/local'

const stigfier = localFont({src: '/../public/fonts/stigfier/Stigfier.woff2'})


export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <div className={stigfier.className}>
     <Component {...pageProps} />
   </div>
  )
}
```

and even creating a link in the '_document.jsx' like so:

```
        <link
        rel="preload"
        href="/../public/fonts/stigfier/Stigfier.ttf"
        as="font"
        type="font/ttf"
        crossOrigin="anonymous"
        />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your fonts are already in the public folder you do not need to specify it.

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: Stigfier;
    src:
         url('/fonts/stigfier/Stigfier.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/stigfier/Stigfier.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('/fonts/stigfier/Stigfier.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/fonts/stigfier/Stigfier.otf') format('opentype');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}

body {
    font-family: Stigfier;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In next/font/local, with src you need to add other properties like weight, display and subset.
also make sure you are working on next 13, because next/font is a new feature which comes under nextjs 13.

read this: [Nextjs 13 features](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13)